# How can I arrange several plots using ipywidgets?

Tags: python, matplotlib, layout, widget, ipython

**Question.**
How can I make a grid (or other similar layout) out of matplotlib plots using ipywidgets?

**Description of my attempt.**
I want to have two plots, each of witch is on separate matplotlib figure. I want them to be converted into ipython widgets and arranged in a such a way that one plot is on the right and other is on the left, but I am getting two plots where first is on top of second.
I tried using HBox and TwoByTwoLayout.

**My code.**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets

output = widgets.Output()
output1 = widgets.Output()

with output:
    with plt.style.context("ggplot"):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
        plt.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6]);
with output1:
    with plt.style.context("ggplot"):
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
        plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,8,5]);

widgets.HBox([output1,output])

from ipywidgets import TwoByTwoLayout 
TwoByTwoLayout(top_left=output,top_right=output1)
```

**Some sources I tried to use.**
Here are some examples that I failed to cannibalize to my code.

[First one,](https://coderzcolumn.com/tutorials/data-science/interactive-charts-using-matplotlib-and-ipywidgets)
[second one,](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Layout%20Templates.html)
[third one.](https://kapernikov.com/ipywidgets-with-matplotlib/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find answer myself.

**My Code.**

```
%matplotlib widget

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets

with plt.ioff():
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    im1 = plt.scatter([1,2,3],[4,3,1])
    
with plt.ioff():
    fig2 = plt.figure()
    im2 = plt.scatter([2,4,3],[1,6,5])
    
display(widgets.HBox([fig1.canvas, fig2.canvas]))
```